# Add Link Before Element ul

Tags: jquery, addition

everyone,

I am still a beginner.

I want to ask, I would like to add a link before the ul tag, as the following code

```
<div id="PageList1" class="widget PageList">
<div class="widget-content">
<ul>
<li class="selected"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I was adding the code `<a href="#" id="pull"> Menu </ a>` and become like this

```
<div id="PageList1" class="widget PageList">
<div class="widget-content">
<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a> /*---I would like to add this.----*/
<ul>
<li class="selected"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to use the `before ()` but it does not work, hopefully you can help me.

```
$("#PageList1 ul").before("<a id="pull" href="#">Menu</a>");
```

or

```
$("#PageList1 .widget-content").prepend("<a href='#' id='pull'>Menu</a>");
```

The code does not work.

thanks, regards

Comment: Show what you tried and we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: With the first one your quotes are broken and the second one targets the wrong element.

Comment: @Musa what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('.widget-content').prepend('<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>');
```

[test it here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp7Ft/);

Comment: I use the selectors 'widget-content' on the other. I just add in the element.

Comment: I tried to add the selector # PageList1 and successfully, thank you, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it using `.before()`

```
$(function(){

    $('#PageList1 ul').before('<a href="#" id="pull"> Menu </ a>');

});
```

See also this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/C7T8P/1/

Comment: 'ul' tag inside element 'Pagelist1', if you use the code tag 'ul' may be added as well

Comment: Sure, you can just add the `#PageList1` in the selector. Updated my answer.

Comment: Did you wrap it in `$(function(){` like I show in the jsFiddle? Updated my answer again. If you are using Chrome, you can hit F12 and bring up "developer tools" and look for a red "x" error on the bottom right. Click that error and that could give you a clue what's not working with the jquery.

Comment: yes I've used it, I've solved the problem, maybe next time I'll ask you again, regards

Comment: Ok no worries. My other thought was it was your quotes. You have to make sure you didn't mix them improperly. Single quotes wrapping the whole statement on the outside, then use double quotes on the inside, or vise-versa. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Following Html code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Link Before the UL</title>
<style type="text/css">
#navlist
{
padding-left:10px;
margin-left:0px;
display:inline;
}
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navcontainer">
<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$('div.widget-content').prepend('<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>');
```

Comment: I've solved the problem, maybe next time I'll ask you again, regards

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("widget-content")[0].innerHTML = "<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>" +document.getElementsByClassName("widget-content")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I use the selectors 'widget-content' on the other. I just add in the element.

Comment: you would have to add a more specific selector, e.g. use getElementsById with an id added to that particular tag, or if you're only using this on one page, replace the 0 in the [ ] to be the number that corresponds to the correct widget-content element

Comment: I've solved the problem, maybe next time I'll ask you again, regards